# Passing different viewmodels in partialview

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, partial-views

I am trying to share a form across multiple views using PartialView using the piece of code below:

This is the model I want to share across all views that implement the partial view

```
namespace CSharp.Models.ViewModels
{
   public class HomeViewModel
   {
      public string County { get; set; }
      public ElectionType? Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Partial View file looks like this:

```
@model CSharp.Models.ViewModels.HomeViewModel
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.County, new { @class = "form-control" })      
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Type, null, new { @class = "form-control"})
```

In one of the files that need to implement the partial view, I have the following code:

```
Home View

@model CSharp.Models.ViewModels.HomeViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Result", new { ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Get, new { role = "form" }))
{
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_PartialViewFile.cshtml", Model)
}
```

When I run the page, it works as it should.

One the other page that requires the partial view, I have this view that uses a ViewModel

```
Manage View
@model CSharp.Models.ViewModels.HomeManageViewModel
<form >
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_PartialViewFile.cshtml", Model.HomeViewModel);
</form>
```

`HomeManageViewModel` looks like this

```
public class HomeManageViewModel
{
    public HomeViewModel HomeViewModel { get; set; }
    public IndexViewModel ManageViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

When I run `Manage View`, I get this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'HomeManageViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'HomeViewModel'

I thought since I'm actually passing `Model.HomeViewModel` in `Manage View` partial view, it *should* work.

How can I pass a view model variable to partial view?

Comment: The rendered partial view in `Manage View` uses `HomeViewModel` instead of `HomeManageViewModel`. You can create separate partial view for `Manage View` view which bound to `HomeManageViewModel` instead, hence partial view model should follows parent view page model.

Comment: Side note: it is always good idea to search for error message (i.e. https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+The+model+item+passed+into+the+dictionary+is+of+type+but+this+dictionary+requires+a+model+item+of+type) which would have given the same explanation as nice answer by Stephen Muecke provided.

Answer (score 5):

It means that the value of property `HomeViewModel` in `HomeManageViewModel` is `null` - you did not initialize it in the GET method before you passed a model to the view, so its `null`. When the model is `null`, the `Partial()` method passes the model declared in the main view.

Either initialize `HomeManageViewModel` and its `HomeViewModel` in the GET method, and pass the model to the view

```
var model = new HomeManageViewModel()
{
    HomeViewModel = new HomeViewModel(){ .... }
}
return View(model);
```

or in the view, you can use

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialViewFile", new HomeViewModel());
```

Note however, that your code will not work in a form because a `Html.Partial()` will not generate the correct name prefix for model binding. Instead use an `EditorTemplate`. Change the name of the partial to `HomeViewModel.cshtml` - to match the name of the class, and place it in the `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder (or the `Views/yourControllerName/EditorTemplates` folder), and then in the main view, use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.HomeViewModel)
```